# Looping through two dimensional array backwards

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, reverse, nested-loops

```
String board [][] = [a,b,c]
                    [d,e,f]

for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
for(int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++){
    String temp = "";
    for(int k=j;k<board[i].length;k++){
        temp = temp+board[i][k];
        System.out.println(temp);
        if(temp.length()>2){
            findWord(temp);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This prints out
a
ab
abc
b
bc
c
d
de
def
e
ef
f
...........

How would I switch around the for loops so that it displayed like:
c
cb
cba
b
ba
a
f
fe
fed
ed
e
d

or

f
fe
fed
e
ed
d
c
cb
cba
b
ba
a

Comment: Do you want to display array in reverse order?

Comment: always use complete source code.so that it become easy for others to compile in their system.

Comment: It is policy to allow edits that *reformat* code, but not that *changes* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++) {
    String temp = "";
    for(int k=j;k<board[i].length;k++) {
    }
  }
}
```

You should start a counter at the length of the array - 1, test if the counter is greater then or equal to 0 and finally decrement your counter. Like this

```
for(int i=board.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
  for(int j=board[i].length-1; j>=0; j--) {
    String temp = "";
    for(int k=j;k>=0;k--) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep - this is the right way around - but I think k starts at `j`, not `j-1`.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
for(int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++){
```

by this

```
for(int i=board.length; i>-1; i--){
for(int j=board[i].length; j>-1; j--){
```

complete loop

```
String board [][] = [a,b,c]
                    [d,e,f]

for(int i=board.length; i>-1; i--){
for(int j=board[i].length; j>-1; j--){
    String temp = "";
    for(int k=j;k<board[i].length;k++){
        temp = temp+board[i][k];
        System.out.println(temp);
        if(temp.length()>2){
            findWord(temp);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: start at length-1 and go all the way to ==0 (not >0). Also - need to count `k` backwards as well...

Comment: I don't see the edit I was looking for. Need `for(int i = board.length - 1;` etc...

Comment: No it doesn't. You start with an index that is out of bounds. It is the start value not the end condition that I am talking about.